# i3wm check if container exists in workspace

Tags: i3

How can I determine in `i3wm` ([layout saving](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html)) if there exists a placeholder/container for certain application? For example I want to check if there exists a placeholder for class `Evince`, how this can be done? I thought of something compare to `ps -fC xxx | grep -o evince`, but I don't know which process represents the "placeholder/container".